# Angular Form Validation Error - Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework

I tried to use angular form to validate user's input in a "ionic generated component" but error as mentioned in the title kept occurring.

Angular forms and validations used in "ionic generated pages" are working fine.

Any ideas?

Picture of :

[HTML Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KObtH.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux3PH.png)

[TypeScript Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A32wZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57251807/9516387

Which is:

You checking for the presence of an error where no error might exist.

You want something like this:

```
f.email.errors?.required
```

Or even:

```
f.email?.errors?.required
```

Do the same for the password field and anywhere else where the property might not exist when it is first called.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to access it by `f.controls.recipientName.errors`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still couldn't fix the problem